# RegOpenKeyEx fails with 87 on Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm trying to open a registry key in Visual Basic 2005 Express:

```
Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Private Const KEY_READ = &H20019    
Dim longResult as Long
Dim hKey as Long
longResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\AppDataLow", 0&, KEY_READ, hKey)
```

but I always get error 87 in longResult.
Since this is Windows 7 64 bit I also tried

```
KEY_READ Or &H100
KEY_READ Or &H200
KEY_READ Or &H300
```

but neither of these worked, always getting 87 return value, meaning "INVALID PARAMETER".
The declaration of RegOpenKeyEx is:

```
Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" ( _
    ByVal hKey As Long, _
    ByVal lpSubKey As String, _
    ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
    ByVal samDesired As Long, _
    ByVal phkResult As Long) As Long
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your declaration is completely wrong, it came from the VB6 era.  Just don't do this, use the RegistryKey class instead.

Comment: Alright. But why would you say that a "different era" is "wrong" though?

Comment: VB6 came from a generation of Visual Basic that was designed to run on 16-bit operating systems.  Ancient history.  A Long is 32 bits in VB6, it is 64 bits in VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read all of [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.regopenkeyex).

Then, import `Microsoft.Win32` and use [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey(v=vs.80).aspx) methods instead.

Comment: Oh actually it works only within the Visual Studio environment, when I build with F5. When I try to run the actual built exe file, some file operations suddenly don't work anymore, but probably unrelated to this.

Comment: If you've got problems running outside of VS, then have a search for admin permissions, etc.  Usually it's because the standard Windows user doesn't have permission for certain things inside the registry structure.